# Wannachart doesn't return a png graphic

Tags: json, graphics, png

I'm using [Wannacharts](http://www.wannacharts.com/) but my json doesn't return a png.
What is the correct json format?

```
{
    "provider_id":xxx,
    "chart_id": xxx,
    "dynamic_title":"Title",
    "dynamic_x_title":"O.S.",
    "dynamic_y_title":"Power (W)",
    "api_key":"xxxxx",
    "data": [{
      "xValue": "f1",
      "yValue": 2331.5
  }],[{
      "xValue": "d3",
      "yValue": 2235
  }],[{
      "xValue": "c1",
      "yValue": 1424.4
  }]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WannaCharts you must send the data field in brakets, not every record inside in brackets.

Like this:

```
{
    "provider_id":xxx,
    "chart_id": xxx,
    "dynamic_title":"Title",
    "dynamic_x_title":"O.S.",
    "dynamic_y_title":"Power (W)",
    "api_key":"xxx",
    "data": [{
      "xValue": "f1",
      "yValue": 2331.5
  },{
      "xValue": "d3",
      "yValue": 2235
  },{
      "xValue": "c1",
      "yValue": 1424.4
  }]
  }
```

remember to fill the api value with your apikey in wannacharts.